# Querying average value on derived table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In my database, I am keeping track of several web pages and how many visitors they receive.

Each page in the `sites` table has several rows of observations in the `readings` table.

I want to maintain all the observation rows in order to keep track of how visitors grows over time on each site, but of course to get a snapshot at a given moment I will want to look at only the most recent observation.

When I am trying to get the average number of visitors at the current moment for a group of sites, I run the following query:

```
SELECT Avg(o.visitors)
  FROM
     (
        SELECT sites.id site_id, 
               r.visitors, 
               Max(r.observation_batch_id) observation_batch_id
        FROM sites s
             JOIN readings r ON s.id = r.site_id
        GROUP BY s.id
     ) o
```

I do not have a lot of experience with SQL, so I'm wondering whether this two-step process is best, where I

1. Create a table by selecting each site and the highest `observation_batch_id` corresponding to that site, since that is the latest observation, and then
2. Get the average of the values in that derived table

Would it be better/possible to do the whole thing in one step? If so, how would I do it?

Comment: Your present query returns indeterminate results for r.visitors

Comment: Sample data and desired result would greatly help.

Comment: @Strawberry I was afraid of that. How can I assure that r.visitors comes from the correct row (i.e. where r.observation_batch_id is the maximum value for that side_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your query is malformed.  You are aggregating by one column (site id) but include the unaggregated value of `visitors` in the `SELECT`.  Your database should be returning an error; newer versions of MySQL generate this error.

You cannot do this easily in one step.  But you can at least write an accurate query.  Surprisingly, you don't need the `sites` table for this.  First, to get the most recent readings, one method is a correlated subquery:

```
select r.*
from readings r
where r.observation_batch_id = (select max(r2.observation_batch_id)
                                from readings r2
                                where r2.site_id = r.site_id
                               );
```

Then you can do everything you want without another subquery:

```
select sum(r.visitors) / count(distinct r.site_id)
from readings r
where r.observation_batch_id = (select max(r2.observation_batch_id)
                                from readings r2
                                where r2.site_id = r.site_id
                               );
```

Comment: Right, MySQL was telling me "Expression of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by".
Glad you were still able to figure out what I was trying to do

Comment: Still trying to wrap my head around this answer, but it seems the key is knowing how to write a correlated subquery, since I need to find the `max(observation_batch_id)`, but that value itself depends on the `site_id` used in the main SELECT statement